# What special handling do we need if we are trying to execute GET in TIdHTTP with Chinese words as parameters

Tags: indy, delphi-10.2-tokyo

I'm trying to GET the following URL in Delphi using `TIdHTTO` but it fails:

```
https://api.sketchengine.eu/bonito/run.cgi/wsketch?lemma=上海&username=agofpos&api_key=ce39ab3f07544e759b068338ac1974e2&corpname=preloaded/zhtenten17_simplified_stf2&format=json
```

Using POSTMAN is OK, though.

Here is my code:

```
url := 'https://api.sketchengine.eu/bonito/run.cgi/wsketch?lemma=上海&username=agofpos&api_key=ce39ab3f07544e759b068338ac1974e2&corpname=preloaded/zhtenten17_simplified_stf2&format=json';
memoResult.Text := idHttp.Get(url);
```

Do we need special handling when dealing with non-English characters during GET? If so, how?

I'm using Delphi 10.2, if that helps.

Comment: I executed the URL in browser and its OK, but not in Indy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URLs do not allow non-ASCII characters (IRIs do, but those are not widely in use yet).  In a URL, you must url-encode any non-ASCII characters (and other reserved) characters, such as with Indy's `TIdURI` class, eg:

```
uses
  ..., IdURI;

url := 'https://api.sketchengine.eu/bonito/run.cgi/wsketch?lemma=' + TIdURI.ParamsEncode('上海') + '&username=agofpos&api_key=ce39ab3f07544e759b068338ac1974e2&corpname=preloaded/zhtenten17_simplified_stf2&format=json';
memoResult.Text := idHttp.Get(url);
```

This will encode the Chinese characters to UTF-8 and then encode those bytes in `%HH` format, eg:

> https://api.sketchengine.eu/bonito/run.cgi/wsketch?lemma=%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7&username=agofpos&api_key=ce39ab3f07544e759b068338ac1974e2&corpname=preloaded/zhtenten17_simplified_stf2&format=json

Notice how the `上海` became `%E4%B8%8A%E6%B5%B7`.

Web browsers, POSTMAN, etc handle this internally for you.  You can confirm this by looking at the raw HTTP request that is actually being transmitted.